# Changing the PH of mead for fermenting necessary?

Tags: fermentation, mead, bacteria, ph, acidity

I’m currently creating a batch of mead.
I’ve watched a lot of videos about the process.
I’ve seen some people do it because they said you need to have it between 3.6 and 3.9 ph. And some just don’t bother and it turns out great.
In the first batch i’m making right now i’ve made no changes to the ph level. And of course made sure to sterilize everything beforehand.
The biggest part i’m sort of concerned about is, *do i actually need to change the PH of my mead to prevent bacteria to grow in there or will the alcohol take care of that.*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

IMHO mead does not generally need any adjustment of pH levels to ferment correctly. It is generally fermented to have a similar level of alcohol to a strong wine - which will not generally support bacterial growth. As the fermentation progresses the pH of the mead will naturally drop due to dissolved carbon dioxide. Mead has been made this way for a long time, long before pH or bacteria had been discovered. Good sanitation of containers and ingredients - and pitching an active yeast - is IMHO all that is required.